# sheet_to_json producing bad array of array

Tags: angular, sheetjs, js-xlsx

Using Angular 9, I am building a step wizard and the first step is to read and parse an `.xlsx` file.

I have a file input defined as such:

```html
<form [formGroup]="steps[currentStep].form">
  <label>Select File to Process</label>
  <input accept=".xlsx"
         autocomplete="off"
         floatPlaceholder="always"
         formControlName="input"
         placeholder="Input"
         type="file"
         (change)="fileChanged($event)">
</form>
```

I then have an interface that represents a one-to-one relationship to a data table, I would define the entire interface but there is like 100 columns (outside of my control and they're all named terribly). But it basically looks like:

```js
export interface IRequestItem {
    ReqItemId: number;
    ReqNum?: string;
    _ReqItem?: number;
    CatNum?: number;
    // ... etc.
}
```

The idea is that the user would upload the `.xlsx` file using the input and then an array of IRequestItem would be created. To do this, here is how the fileChanged event handler is setup:

```js
fileChanged(e): void {
    this.steps[this.currentStep].loading = true;
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    reader.onload = (event) => {
        const data = reader.result;
        const workBook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
        if (workBook.SheetNames.length === 0) {
            this.steps[this.currentStep].loading = false;
            return;
        }
        const worksheet = workBook.Sheets[workBook.SheetNames[0]];
        this.workSheet = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json<IRequestItem>(worksheet, {
            blankrows: false,
            header: 1,
            raw: true,
            rawNumbers: true
        });

        this.steps[this.currentStep].loading = false;
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}
```

Basically it does the following:

1. Set the `loading` property of the current step
2. Get the file contents using a FileReader

   - Step 3 would be executed after the file contents are read
3. Get the FileReader results and convert it to an `XLSX.WorkBook`

   - If the user uploads an empty workbook then unset the `loading` property and return
4. Get the first worksheet of the workbook
5. Try to convert the worksheet to an array of `IRequestItem` using the `XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json<T>` method

Everything appears to run fine up until step 5, but if setup a debugger on that line the output in the console is an array of array.

What I don't understand about this is that I'm creating the `.xlsx` file by querying the table in SSMS, exporting the results as a `.CSV` file, and then saving the file using the `.xlsx` extension (in Microsoft Excel). So I know for a fact that not only is my file properly setup but I also know that the data represents a legit IRequestItem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a long while of searching, I realized that I misread the documentation. Per https://docs.sheetjs.com/#json I was specifying the wrong `header` property in the Sheet2JSONOpts. Instead, it should have been:

```ts
this.workSheet = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json<IRequestItem>(worksheet, {
  blankrows: false,
  header: 'A',
  raw: true,
  rawNumbers: true
});
```